# Redirect one domain to other using hosts file or similar

Tags: hosts, redirection

Usually, the syntax in the /etc/hosts file is

```
IP hostname alias1 alias2
```

but I want to make something like

```
SERVER  SERVER2
```

but I don't want to specify the SERVER IP in the file, only the host name.

Is there any way to achieve it, with this file or any other?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to easily achieve what you want is to simply insert the record if you have your own DNS server, or see if your router allows you to insert custom zones.

However, you will probably still have the same problem as (If I understand what you want to do) remote servers usually need to be configured for host headers if the server hosts more than one website.