# Hosts file redirect to domain

Tags: hosts-file

In the hosts file how do I make it instead of redirecting to an IP address redirect to either a domain(example.com) or a URL on an IP address(127.0.0.1/example.html)? I tried typing it in but it doesn't work. I need to know how for Windows and Linux. How can I do it without a program or DNS?

Comment: Windows or linux? You can use simpledns.com for Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I redirect a domain to another domain locally?](http://superuser.com/questions/601574/how-do-i-redirect-a-domain-to-another-domain-locally), also see: [Can't map certain port and path with hosts file](http://superuser.com/questions/344870/cant-map-certain-port-and-path-with-hosts-file), http://superuser.com/questions/732135/editing-etc-hosts-to-use-domain-name-instead-of-ip-address, http://superuser.com/questions/97213/redirect-one-domain-to-other-using-hosts-file-or-similar,

Comment: How can I do it without a program or DNS?

Comment: Do you want to redirect requests or map one domain's IP to another one? `hosts` file doesn't redirect anything, it overrides DNS lookups (so domains are resolved to IPs from `hosts`). So do you want to redirect requests pointed at a domain, or resolve that domain's IP to another domain's IP?

Comment: map one domain to another IP

Comment: Then `nslookup` that second domain and use its IP in `hosts` file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hosts file is called **hosts** for a reason, it is about exactly that, hosts. You can redirect a hostname to a different IP, but not a specific location at that ip. What you are trying to do is not supported, because you aren't directing a host to an IP, you are directing to an address.

**Single Hostname:**

```
1.2.3.4.5.6    example.com     # redirects example to example ip
```

**Double Hostnames:**

```
1.2.3.4.5.6    example.com     example.net    # redirects examples to example ip
```

Comment: +1, great first answer. I don't see many new users start off this well.