# Add hostname synonym

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, hosts-file

I'm attempting allow a hostname to used as synonyms for another hostname.

For example : configure `mymachine.com` to be a synonym for `localhost:8080` so if `mymachine.com` is navigated to in browser the url that is used in background is `localhost:8080` .

I have tried modifying windows hosts file but this is incorrect as hosts file is used for resolving hostnames to ip addresses, not resolving hostnames to other hostnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost is always 127.0.0.1, so your hosts file can read `mymachine.com 127.0.0.1` and it will resolve to localhost.

Also, you can alias as many host names as you like to that same address.

Comment: thank you, is machine restart required ? hostname is not being resovled.

Comment: seems should be "127.0.0.1 mymachine.com"  http://superuser.com/questions/834716/hosts-file-redirect-to-domain ?